# ProgressBar inside a Fragment in ViewPager does not get updated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-progressbar

I have a ProgressBar on my fragment_main.xml.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_total"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:indeterminate="false" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And I have this code in fragment which is bound via an adapter to a ViewPager.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int random = new Random().nextInt(100);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ProgressBar progressTotal = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_total);
    progressTotal.setProgress(random);

    TextView progressText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_text);
    progressText.setText(Integer.toString(random));

    return rootView;
}
```

The progress bar and text loads the first time. Then I reset the adapter on a button click to make the fragments reload. I get the random progress updated in the text, but never on the progress bar. Tried custom drawables, invalidating, setting the progress to zero first, setting max values, etc but nothing seem to work.

What am I missing here?

PS: This is how I reset the adapter from my activity

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Comment: How do you reset the adapter?Create a new instance or just notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Can you post the some code about "reset the adapter on a button click to make the fragments reload"?I think it will be more clear.

Comment: @AvatarQing: I create a new instance of the fragment adapter and call setAdapter on the viewpager.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: I tried setting the max to 100 but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out setting the adapter not necessarily instantiate new fragments and all. Doh!

Had to do the removing of the fragments manually until they started showing up correctly.

Basically I had to call the below method before setting the adapter again.

```
private void reinitializeFragments() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
        transaction.remove(fragment);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```